SwiftUI with Metal synchronize issue
I am writing a SwiftUI with Metal project on macOS, and that drawing the screen capture on external monitor with renderer in SwiftUI. I uses triple buffering with semaphore for synchronizing the CPU and GPU drawing, but there is something wrong.
At the beginning, I set the first screen capture on buffer 1, that renderer drawing first time using buffer 0 with a default picture. Then capturing the second one on buffer 2 that renderer drawing buffer 1. If capturing the third one on buffer 0, the renderer drawing the buffer 2, and so on.
There is an issue that if the screen is still, then the last capturing screen won't be draw.
Below is pseudo code:
currentIndex = 0

func setRenderData(data) {
    semaphore_wait()

    let nextBufferIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % InFlightBufferCount
    setTexture(data, nextBufferIndex)
    print("setData, index=\(nextBufferIndex)")
}

func draw(in view: MTKView) {

    ...

    renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(TextureBuffer[currentIndex])
    commandBuffer.addCompletionHandler() { _ in
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    commandBuffer.commit()
    print("commit, index=\(currentIndex)")
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % InFlightBufferCount
}


I modify my solution using two indexes, one for setting the screen capture buffer, and one for drawing screen capture.
When setting buffer 0 for first screen capture, and immediately the SwiftUI issue draw to renderer rendering the buffer 0, the external monitor will become flickered.
below is modified pseudo code, only update setRenderData():
currentIndex = 0
setDataIndex = 0

func setRenderData(data) {
    semaphore_wait()

    setTexture(data, setDataIndex)
    print("setData, index=\(setDataIndex)")
    setDataIndex = (setDataIndex + 1) % InFlightBufferCount
}

func draw(in view: MTKView) {

    ...

    renderEncoder.setFragmentTexture(TextureBuffer[currentIndex])
    commandBuffer.addCompletionHandler() { _ in
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    commandBuffer.commit()
    print("commit, index=\(currentIndex)")
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % InFlightBufferCount
}

And the log as below, it shows the commits are always after set data done:
[16:49:10.261] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.271] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.277] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.281] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.291] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.294] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.300] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.310] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.313] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.327] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.329] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.343] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.346] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.360] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.362] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.377] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.379] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.394] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.396] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.410] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.412] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.428] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.431] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.444] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.446] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.461] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.464] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.477] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.479] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.494] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.496] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.511] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.513] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.528] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.530] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.544] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.546] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.561] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.563] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.577] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.579] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.594] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.597] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.611] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.613] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.628] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.630] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.645] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.647] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.661] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.663] setRenderDataNormalized(). set BufferIndex=2
[16:49:10.677] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=0
[16:49:10.694] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=1
[16:49:10.712] draw() commandBuffer.commit(), currentBufferIndex=2

I checked the log shown setRenderData done then run draw() with the same index. But I don't know why it becomes flickered. By Apple "Metal Best Practices Guide" , said Advance the current frame index, which determines the correct dynamic data buffer for the frame, is that mean CPU set render data should advance GPU rendering index? But that way the last frame won't be drawn?
Or say, how to manage such kinds of synchronization?
